# RadioButton and list, text not in line with radio

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Hello I've got something like this

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1"
            RepeatColumns="2"
            RepeatDirection="Vertical"
            RepeatLayout="Table"
            TextAlign="Left"
            runat="server">
             <asp:ListItem Text="Nacional" Value="nacional" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="Departamental" Value="departamental" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="Politica" Value="politica" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="Sociales" Value="social" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="Policial" Value="policial" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="Deportes" Value="deporte" />
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

[image]

As you can see the Text is slightly higher and it looks really odd, why does this happen?

here I added the html

```
    <div class="formline">
        <table id="MainContent_RadioButtonList1">
<tr>
    <td><label for="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_0">Nacional</label><input id="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="nacional" /></td><td><label for="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_3">Sociales</label><input id="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="social" /></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><label for="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_1">Departamental</label><input id="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="departamental" /></td><td><label for="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_4">Policial</label><input id="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_4" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="policial" /></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><label for="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_2">Politica</label><input id="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="politica" /></td><td><label for="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_5">Deportes</label><input id="MainContent_RadioButtonList1_5" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButtonList1" value="deporte" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show also the generated html in the browser

Comment: where do I get that from? f12?

Comment: Just right-click on the page and click on "show source code"(or how it's called in your language and browser).

Comment: done! my internet was down for a bit sorry

Comment: What happens if you change `RepeatLayout="Table"` to `RepeatLayout="Flow"`? Show the css-class `formline`.

Comment: I get the same issue but now it's on one column
https://i.gyazo.com/65c0d3f44b8b2ed33033f8dc8460cefd.png
 
and due to copy paste from an older project formline does not currently even exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dafault behavior of the `RadioButtonList` control is to display the text and the radio button adjecent to one another,if they are not adjecent it means somewhere in your web application you have a CSS rule which changed the default behavior.

You can use F12 in Google Chrome to inspect the HTML and CSS and try find which style rule is causing the problem:

[image: Using developer tools in Google Chrome]

You can also try adding the style rule below to the page where you have the `RadioButtonList` control, just make sure you add it **after** all the other CSS refrences:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table#RadioButtonList1 td
    {
        vertical-align:top;
        height:100px;
    }
</style>
```